# ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (6 for 4..5)) with rails, active admin and simple form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, activeadmin, simple-form, formtastic

I have an app with rails4, activeadmin and simpleform. I have changed my simple_form.rb config. Since then, when I visit localhost:3000/admin/login, I get:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (6 for 4..5)):
    5:   <%= active_admin_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => send(:"#{scope}_session_path"), :html => { :id => "session_new" }) do |f|
    6:     f.inputs do
    7:       resource.class.authentication_keys.each { |key| f.input key, :input_html => {:autofocus => true}}
    8:       f.input :password
    9:       f.input :remember_me, :label => t('active_admin.devise.login.remember_me'), :as => :boolean, :if =>  false  #devise_mapping.rememberable? }
    10:     end
    11:     f.actions do
  simple_form (2.1.0) lib/simple_form/inputs/base.rb:50:in `initialize'
  formtastic (2.2.1) lib/formtastic/helpers/input_helper.rb:240:in `new'
  formtastic (2.2.1) lib/formtastic/helpers/input_helper.rb:240:in `input'
...
```

Gemfile.lock:

```
...
rails (3.2.13)
activeadmin (0.6.0)
formtastic (2.2.1)
simple_form (2.1.0)
```

What's causing the error?

Answer (score 0):

On this thread: https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/2703, SpecialCyCi has a hack that fixes the issue.

At the top of `config/initializers/simple_form.rb`, put the following:

```
inputs = %w[
  CollectionSelectInput
  DateTimeInput
  FileInput
  GroupedCollectionSelectInput
  NumericInput
  PasswordInput
  RangeInput
  StringInput
  TextInput
]

inputs.each do |input_type|
  superclass = "SimpleForm::Inputs::#{input_type}"
  hack = %|
    module SimpleForm
      module Inputs
        class #{superclass}
          def input_html_classes
            super.push('form-control')
          end
        end
      end
    end
  |
  eval(hack)

end

SimpleForm.setup do |config|
  # your config here...
  # ...
end
```